# Is there any way to choose live streaming source having best performance with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, live-streaming

I am building a html5 page which will embed a `RTMP` live streaming on desktop and use `ffmpeg` to convert the streaming into `Mpeg` for mobile version. I am using `video.js` and `jsmpeg` to play the streaming.

The probelm is :

I got a number of streaming sources, so I am wandering is there any way to choose the source having best performance? Could I use JavaScript to test the quality of the streaming source?

PRACTICAL CODE EXAMPLE：

```js
// I got several source
let streamingSrc1 = "ws://192.168.124.227:8084";
let streamingSrc2 = "ws://192.168.133.228:8086";
let streamingSrc3 = "ws://192.168.155.229:8088";

////// Could I get the quality of streaming source before I decide to use it? 
let jsmpegSrc = streamingSrc1;
// or 
// let jsmpegSrc = streamingSrc2;
// or
// let jsmpegSrc = streamingSrc3;


// create jsmpeg player
let canvasId = "mpegPlayer";
let canvasDOM = document.getElementById(canvasId);
let player = new JSMpeg.Player(jsmpegSrc, {
    canvas: canvasDOM,
    videoBufferSize: 128 * 1024,
});
```

Thank a lot for your help

Comment: Define "quality of the streaming source".

Comment: My goal is to choose the source having less delay!